# Strange behavior when creating new dates in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, date, ecmascript-6

I was playing around with the `Date` object in JavaScript and found a very strange behavior.

If you create a new date with 1 parameter and call the `getFullYear` method, it will return 1 less than what you passed in

```
new Date("2014").getFullYear()
=> 2013
```

To test a theory, that it would return "2014-1-1", and in the previous timezone, the year before, I did another test.

```
new Date("2014").getDate()
=> 31

new Date("2014").getMonth()
=> 11
```

This would support the timezone theory, but it still doesn't explain the next two examples.

If you type in an alphanumeric string, you will get the correct year. It even works for gibberish like this

```
new Date("hsdkjfuweirsdf 2014").getFullYear();
=> 2014
```

For the first example, I assumed the function started counting at 0, so the year would be 1 less. However, that doesn't explain why my second function returned the correct year.

Edit:

I found another strange behavior with the `new Date()` constructor. If you pass in multiple parameters, it will return the correct year as well

```
new Date("2014", "9").getFullYear()
=> 2014
```

All of the above tests were done multiple times in Google Chrome.

Comment: which browser? works fine on chrome for me.

Comment: The first is likely due to a mixture of timezones – `"2014"` is parsed as `2014-01-01 00:00:00 UTC`. Then, `getFullYear()` returns the year in your local timezone (UTC-N hours, placing it in 2013). Note: This behavior changed officially between ES5 (what you're seeing) and ES6.

Comment: new Date("2014").getFullYear() is returning 2014 for me in chrome and firefox

Comment: Just did another test and `new Date('2014').getDate()` returns 31, which would support Jonathan's theory. But this doesn't explain the examples where letters are included before the year

Comment: It's not a theory, print `new Date('2014')`, you'll see the time and timezone. For me, in Iron (a Chromium fork), Internet Explorer, Edge and NodeJS, the date is created with local timezone and `new Date("2014").getFullYear()` returns 2014. In Firefox, I get a date in GMT but `getFullYear()` also returns in GMT so I get 2014.

Comment: `'hsdkjfuweirsdf 2014'` doesn’t parse as a date in Firefox. When you pass two or more arguments to the constructor, the reliable constructor `new Date(year, month[, day[, hour[, minutes[, seconds[, milliseconds]]]]])` is used. Rule of thumb: don’t rely on the browser to parse dates. They all have different implementations.

Comment: The only date formats that are guaranteed to be parseable are RFC 2822 and ISO 8601.

Comment: You act like `Date` is a blackbox and you have to prod it with various inputs to figure out what it's doing. Have you tried the [explicitly supported behaviour(s)](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-date-constructor) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first case, the date string is being detected as partially following the one official [Date Time String Format](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15):

> ECMAScript defines a string interchange format for date-times based upon a simplification of the ISO 8601 Extended Format. The format is as follows: **`YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ`**

And, at least with the 5th edition of ECMAScript, that your browser is currently adhering to:

> The value of an absent time zone offset is “**Z**”.

With this, the date string is assumed to be in UTC/GMT time for parsing.

```
Date.parse("2014") === Date.parse("2014-01-01T00:00:00Z");
```

Then, `getFullYear()` provides the year for the same "moment" in your local time zone, compared to its equivalent `UTC` method.

```
new Date("2014").getFullYear()    // 2013 (or 2014 for users in UTC+N timezones)
new Date("2014").getHours()       // (not 0, unless you live in UTC+0)

new Date("2014").getUTCFullYear() // 2014
new Date("2014").getUTCHours()    // 0
```

---

The 2nd example, by including the gibberish before the year, fails to match the above format, even partially.

Since that's the only format officially defined in the specification, the browser is now [on its own to determine if and how it should parse the date string](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-date.parse).

> If the String does not conform to [the Date Time String Format] the function may fall back to any implementation-specific heuristics or implementation-specific date formats.

And, it chooses to use your local time zone by default and largely ignore the gibberish.

```
new Date("hsdkjfuweirsdf 2014").getFullYear() // 2014
new Date("hsdkjfuweirsdf 2014").getHours()    // 0
```

---

Note: The [most recent, 6th edition of ECMAScript](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-date-time-string-format) has changed the assumed value for date strings lacking timezones:

> If the time zone offset is absent, the date-time is interpreted as a local time.

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely an effect of `Date` parsing for UTC vs local time zone.

Generally, if you give any string that can be "fit" to [ISO 8601 format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) the `Date()` constructor will try to parse you a *GMT-located* object.  Otherwise it will give you your own local (with your browser's timezone info) object.

```
// how many minutes to add to get GMT?
var tzOffset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset()
// 300    // Eastern Standard Time, GMT-5

// will be parsed as GMT:
var gmt = new Date("2011");

// what year is it for me?
gmt.getFullYear()
// 2010
```

This is the local year when GMT experiences January 1, 2011. (It's still 2010 in NYC when London celebrates the New Year)

Notably, there are UTC functions:

```
// what year is it in London?
gmt.getUTCFullYear()
// 2011
```

Let's see what happens when we "add" hours so that our local time catches up:

```
// add tzOffset, voila, "correct" year
var localyear = new Date(gmt.getTime() + tzOffset*60*1000).getFullYear()
// 2011
```

Also, Chrome does a "best effort" to parse junk (non-standard) strings. This is browser-dependent behavior, and rely on it at your own risk.  This explains the local-time-located behavior for strings such as `"hsdkjfuweirsdf 2014"`.